# Showing every n number of titles in one slide of content slider

Tags: jquery

I'm using [Uno slider](http://unoslider.npmedia.net/) , 
I have some Titles which I want to show every "n" number of them in one slide,
currently it only shows one title per slide,
Is there any way to put more than 1 item in one slide?

Html Markup:

```
<div class="article-content-holder">
<ul class="article-titles-holder">
    <li>title </li>
    <li>title </li>
    <li>title </li>
    <li>title </li>
    <li>title </li>
    <li>title </li>
    <li>title </li>
    <li>title </li>
    <li>title </li>
    <li>title </li>
    <li>title </li>
    <li>title </li>
    <li>title </li>
    <li>title </li>
</ul>
<div class="unoSliderNav"></div>
</div>
```

### Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bqjnW/)

Is there any way to do it without touching the core , that would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found a solution for this: wrap every n elements inside a div with a certain class first:

```
    var titles = $(".article-titles-holder li");
for(var i = 0; i < titles.length; i+=10) {
  titles.slice(i, i+10).wrapAll("<div class='title-slide'></div>");
}
```

Then append Uno Slider and make it select your div's class:

```
window.unoSlider = $('#titles-holder').unoSlider({
                                                         selector:".title-slide"
                                                         });
```

There it is, It shows every n (10 in this case) elements in one slide

Comment: Ah, you figured it out? Excellent, I'd assumed there was a change in the UI that I'd missed (was browsing meta to see what it might be). And +1.

Comment: @DavidThomas Thank you very much , I really appreciate your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

The slider just targets the `<li>` elements by default. There's an option to pass a different selector into the `.unoSlider()` function, so try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gyWkg/1/). Every slide needs to be distinct so that the plugin's `.find()` call can find them. with a simple selector.

Comment: Well there is one problem and that is the list which comes from cms, so I can't change the markup

Comment: Ok, Your answer lead me to the right direction, I wrapped every 10 elements inside a div first, then I used selector, Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please mark it as accepted once SO allows. :)

Comment: Sure i will, please complete your answer with the wrapping part so people who might come here later can use it too, Thanks.